# Batch file that will search wildcard folders for a file, and if file does not exists, delete folder

Tags: batch, script

So say I have a multiple folders named "Example93947" with the "93947" being a random string added to each folder. Only one of these folders actually has files in it. What I want to do is create a batch file that finds each folder named "Example*", looks in it for particular file(s) (asdf.txt for example) and if the file isn't there, delete the folder. If it is there, leave it alone.

I'd been trying to do something involving like:

```
for /d %%G in (C:\Users\Nastr0nd\Documents\Example*\asdf.txt) DO rd /s /q "%%~G"
```

or

```
for /d %%G in (C:\Users\Nastr0nd\Documents\Example*) do (

If exist C:\Users\Nastr0nd\Documents\Example*\asdf.txt echo y

if not exist asdf.txt rd /s /q "%%~G"
```

Comment: What OS? 32-bit or 64-bit? If all you are trying to do is remove empty directories: `for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad') do rd "%%d" 2>NUL` This will remove every empty sub-directory and leave every directory that contains at least one file.  You said only one folder has files in it.

Comment: win10 64 bit. And I don't want to remove any empty file, just the ones that contain "Example*" and are empty

Comment: You said "Only one of the folders actually has files in it".  If that is not correct remove it from your question.

Comment: You want to remove every empty folder named "Example*"? `for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad example*') do rd "%%d" 2>NUL`

Comment: Correct your comment: "And I don't want to remove any empty file"

Comment: `dir /b /s asdf.txt 2>&1 | FINDSTR /I /n /c:"File Not Found">NUL || for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad example*') do rd "%%d" 2>NUL`

Comment: I said that in context of folders named "Example*". There could be other folders not following the "Example*" convention without files that I wouldn't want deleted, that's why I'm asking about folders with that name specifically. Sorry if that was unclear to you.

Comment: Also looks like that worked! Appreciate it.